# Why firebase-core has so many dependendencies?

Tags: android, firebase, dependencies

I added only one line to app.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.2'
```

As a result, these libraries have added:

[image: screenshot]

Does firebase really use them all? I didn't use support libraries before, but now I have to.
Can I get rid these deps?

**UPDATE**: I conducted an investigation to find out the cause of all the dependencies:

[image: without dependencies]

[image: only billing]

[image: only firebase-core]

[image: only google-services]

As you can see the most of dependencies have come from `firebase-core`.

Answer (score 2):

No, they are not all related to firebase, the libraries with versions `25.2.0` are support libraries from android. To learn more read this:

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages.html

You cannot remove them, as they are inside `maven` which is declared in your build.gradle file:

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
  }
}
```

The libraries with version `11.6.2` are all related to firebase, since firebase has to have all libraries with same version number. According to this [Firebase Libraries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available_libraries) the firebase core are used to add analytics services, but also for firebase to work it uses the other libraries like `com.google.android.gms:play-services-task-11.6.2`

Comment: Does gradle include support libraries into my project? Can I use them as regular dependencies?

Why does google's maven do it? Where can I read about it?

Comment: android added its support libraries inside maven, they were in jcenter before, https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#google-maven

Comment: When I remove `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.2'`, it removes all "External libraries" like `support`. I don't undestand this behaviour... As I don't undestand WHY did android add its support libraries inside maven and add it to my project.

Comment: do you only have `'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.2'` in your dependencies?

Comment: No, I use `com.android.billingclient:billing:1.0` that also adds itself and `annotations`. Removing it doesn't affect to support dependencies.

Comment: anw all those support libraries, you actually need them in your code @Dem0n13 so im not sure why you want to remove them... here you can see what those libraries have (classes,interfaces..)https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html

Comment: I really know what do they do. I don't know why did they add to my project, although I don't want it and I don't use it!

Comment: what do you mean? " i dont know why did they add to my project, I told you its in maven in the build.gradle in ALL android projects in the world! your gonna have to use these libraries if u want to use alert dialog for example... @Dem0n13 these libraries are there to help you

Comment: @Dem0n13 yes of course all 11.6.2 versions are firebase versions but firebase is a service that you are adding to your android app so to interact with android it needs the other android libraries also to be able to be used in android